# Zurb Foundation Tooltip: bottom tooltip, but have pip on the right

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation, pip, right-align

I currently have a short link that I want a [Foundation tooltip](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html) for, and the tooltip has to be beneath the link (tip-bottom). Normally, the Foundation tooltip has the pip on the left (and the tooltip expands to the right), but this won't work for me because my link is near the right of the screen. I want the pip to be on the right, and for the tooltip to expand to the left.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUzUl.png) to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's no built-in way to do it. [Zurb forum post](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/25612-tooltip-tip-bottom-but-have-pip-on-right)